# Sort data.frame on one categorical column but alternate according to pattern in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have two possible types of datasets:

```
test6 <- data.frame(S=c("B","Z","B","Z","B","Z","B","B","B","Z","Z","Z"),w=c(1,1.2,1.3,2,0.9,0.95,1,1.5,1,1.1,0.8,1.3))
test5 <- data.frame(S=c("B","Z","B","Z","B","Z","B","B","Z","Z"),w=c(1,1.2,1.3,2,0.9,0.95,1,1.5,1.1,0.8))
```

I want to order them to get this end result,
for test6:

```
   S    w
1  B 1.00
3  B 1.30
5  B 0.90
2  Z 1.20
4  Z 2.00
6  Z 0.95
7  B 1.00
8  B 1.50
9  B 1.00
10 Z 1.10
11 Z 0.80
12 Z 1.30
```

For test5:

```
   S    w
1  B 1.00
3  B 1.30
5  B 0.90
2  Z 1.20
4  Z 2.00
7  B 1.00
8  B 1.50
6  Z 0.95
9  Z 1.10
10 Z 0.80
```

So getting an alternate sorting with 3 B followed by 3 Z in test6 case, and 3 B followed by 2 Z, then 2 B followed by 3 Z and so on.
I found one way to do it with:

```
library(groupdata2)
fold(test6, k = 2,method="n_dis",cat_col = "S")
```

Which creates groups that I can then sort on to achieve this result but this only works in the test6 case i.e same counts of S categories in each group.
Anyone have better, more simple ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain how you determine the 3/2 grouping? For instance, my (partial) answer on `test5` produces B/Z groups of 3,3,2,2 but not 3,2,2,3 as in your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

(Partial answer.)

For the alternating-3s, that's not too hard:

```r
ind <- ave(rep(1, nrow(test6)), test6$S, FUN = function(z) (seq_along(z)-1) %/% 3)
ind
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1

test6[order(ind, test6$S),]
#    S    w
# 1  B 1.00
# 3  B 1.30
# 5  B 0.90
# 2  Z 1.20
# 4  Z 2.00
# 6  Z 0.95
# 7  B 1.00
# 8  B 1.50
# 9  B 1.00
# 10 Z 1.10
# 11 Z 0.80
# 12 Z 1.30
```

With your `test5`, this same method comes close but the 3/2 groupings are not in the same order:

```r
ind <- ave(rep(1, nrow(test5)), test5$S, FUN = function(z) (seq_along(z)-1) %/% 3)
ind
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1

test5[order(ind, test5$S),]
#    S    w
# 1  B 1.00
# 3  B 1.30
# 5  B 0.90
# 2  Z 1.20
# 4  Z 2.00
# 6  Z 0.95
# 7  B 1.00
# 8  B 1.50
# 9  Z 1.10
# 10 Z 0.80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` in combination with `rep` to get a number which can be used in `order`.

```
i <- test6$S == "B"
x <- integer(length(i))
x[i] <- cumsum(rep(c(2,0,0), length.out=sum(i))) - 1
x[!i] <- cumsum(rep(c(2,0,0), length.out=sum(!i)))
test6[order(x),]
#   S    w
#1  B 1.00
#3  B 1.30
#5  B 0.90
#2  Z 1.20
#4  Z 2.00
#6  Z 0.95
#7  B 1.00
#8  B 1.50
#9  B 1.00
#10 Z 1.10
#11 Z 0.80
#12 Z 1.30
```

```
i <- test5$S == "B"
x <- integer(length(i))
x[i] <- cumsum(rep(c(2,0,0,2,0), length.out=sum(i))) - 1
x[!i] <- cumsum(rep(c(2,0,2,0,0), length.out=sum(!i)))
test5[order(x),]
#   S    w
#1  B 1.00
#3  B 1.30
#5  B 0.90
#2  Z 1.20
#4  Z 2.00
#7  B 1.00
#8  B 1.50
#6  Z 0.95
#9  Z 1.10
#10 Z 0.80
```